Playing a video saved by ffmpeg on a rendertexture in unity
I am recording a rendertexture to a stream and saving that directly to a video using the below code.
I can play the videos created using VLC and Media Player (on windows)
However I can't get unity to load these videos in and play them in a videoplayer so i can play them back to the user.
Any suggestions on what might be going wrong?
private void ExportFramesToVideo(List<byte[]> frameData)
{
    string dateTimeStamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss");
    OutputFileName = $"mm_{dateTimeStamp}_output_video.mp4";
    OutputFilePath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, $"{OutputFileName}");

    string frameFolderPath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, $"Frames_{dateTimeStamp}");
    if (!Directory.Exists(frameFolderPath))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(frameFolderPath);
    }

    // SaveFramesAsPNG(frameData, frameFolderPath);

    string ffmpegCommand = $"-y " +
        $"-f rawvideo " +
        $"-pix_fmt rgba " +
        $"-s {renderTexture.width}x{renderTexture.height} " +
        $"-r {animationFrameRate} " +
        $"-i - " +
        $"-vf \"vflip\" " +
        $"-an " +
        $"-c:v libx264 " +
        $"-profile:v baseline " +
        $"-pix_fmt yuv420p " +
        $"-color_primaries bt709 " +
        $"-color_trc bt709 " +
        $"-colorspace bt709 " +
        $"{OutputFilePath}";

    ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = "ffmpeg",
        Arguments = ffmpegCommand,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardInput = true,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        CreateNoWindow = true
    };

    Process process = new Process { StartInfo = processStartInfo };

    process.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, args) => UnityEngine.Debug.Log(args.Data);
    process.Start();
    process.BeginErrorReadLine();

    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        using (var inputStream = process.StandardInput.BaseStream)
        {
            foreach (var frame in frameData)
            {
                inputStream.Write(frame, 0, frame.Length);
            }
        }

        process.StandardInput.Close();
        process.WaitForExit();

        if (process.ExitCode == 0)
        {
            UnityEngine.Debug.Log($"Video successfully created at: {OutputFilePath}");
        }
        else
        {
            UnityEngine.Debug.LogError("FFmpeg process failed.");
        }

        frameBuffer.Clear();
    });
}


I ended up playing it directly from the buffer instead of rendering first.
